# Packaging Your Python Code

Tags: python

I wish to package a utility that I have created that depends on Pillow, a port of the Python Imaging Library. Is there a way to *include* Pillow in my own package or to automatically install Pillow upon running the setup script?

Comment: You can put the pillow library in a directory called `libraries` in your project's directory. Then do `sys.path.append("libraries")` and use the library as usual.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for something like cxfreeze?
http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: @Kyrubas No, I know how to package as an executable.

Comment: Does the method have to be platform-independent?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes, it must be platform independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3 mainly uses pip for installing packages. This is based off of setuptools and distribute. You would create the setup.py script with the requirement specified. The easiest way is to create a requirements file using pip. http://codeinthehole.com/writing/using-pip-and-requirementstxt-to-install-from-the-head-of-a-github-branch/

Command Line:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

setup.py

```
import setuptools
from pip.req import parse_requirements

requirements = [str(ir.req)
                for ir in parse_requirements("requirements.txt", session=uuid.uuid1())
                    if ir.req is not None]
setuptools.setup(..., install_requires=requirements)
```

If you want to build an executable then the process if fairly similar to the standard setup.py file approach only you use cx_freeze.